# reversing text file in C

Tags: c

I wrote the following code but when i enter "abcd" it shows "dcb" and skips the first character.I know that my logic in the while loop crosses the file boundary but fseek(f2) is still not 0 when it crosses the file boundary.It should return some negative value.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f1,*f2;
    char ch;

    clrscr();

    f1=fopen("Input","w");

    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
            putc(ch,f1);


    fclose(f1);

    f2=fopen("Input","r");

    fseek(f2,-1L,2);

    while(ftell(f2)!=0)
    {
            ch=getc(f2);
            printf("%c",ch);
            fseek(f2,-2L,1);
    }

    fclose(f2);

    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `fseek(f2,-1L,2);`  Please don't do this. Include the proper header file (stdio.h) and use the constants SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END.

Comment: The biggest mistake here is that you are trying to reverse a *file* as if it were a *string*.

Comment: If this is not just an exercise, remember that this will fail for any multibyte encoding (like utf-8) and no, using wchar_t won't help: unicode combining characters will be messed up.

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight implied, you really don't want to do things this way. You want to work in reasonable-sized blocks (say, a minimum of 8K), reverse them, and swap positions between one at the beginning and  one at the end (assuming the file is at least 2 blocks, of course).

Answer (score 5):

You need a do-while loop, not a while-do loop.

You need to read the character when ftell() returns zero, but NOT read anymore.  That's usually the indication you need a bottom-tested loop and not a top tested one.

Comment: i changed the loop to 

do
    {
            ch=getc(f2);
            printf("%c",ch);
            fseek(f2,-2L,1);
    }while(ftell(f2)!=0);

but still it misses the last character...?

Comment: The "next" action is backspacing a position (2 positions, since you just read one).  The termination condition is you can't backspace.  So, move the fseek() into the condition and test that you can backspace.  That makes the condition "(ftell(f2) != 0 && fseek(f2, -2L, SEEK_CUR) == 0)".  With your current ftell(), you may invoke it when you're already at BOF.  Don't call functions when you're not sure they won't produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int ch;

    fp=fopen("out.txt","w");

    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
        fputc(ch,fp);

    fclose(fp);

    fp=fopen("out.txt","rb");

    fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_END);

    while(fseek(fp,-2L,SEEK_CUR)==0){
        ch=fgetc(fp);
        putchar(ch);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This is a very clean solution, but some C libraries will not return an error for seeking before the start of the file.  Add an ftell() before the fseek() and you should be covered for all library behaviors.

Comment: I do not think clean. I do not think a good way that use  fseek to reverse the stream.
So, Do anyone fix the program if necessary.